# How memory management system in OpenCV actually work?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

Consider this code:

```
    Size size(227,227);

    for(int i;i<=25000;i++)
    {
      Mat temp;
      resize(imread(strcat(image_address,itoa(i))),temp,size);
      data_.push_back(temp);
    }
```

The size of the image dataset in the disk (its address is passed to image_address) is about 250M. But the resulting program takes 4G of my RAM.Why?
If I changed it to :

```
    Size size(227,227);
    Mat temp;
    for(int i;i<=25000;i++)
    {
      resize(imread(strcat(image_address,itoa(i))),temp,size);
      data_.push_back(temp);
    }
```

my problem solved but the refcount of each of data_ element become 25000 at the end. Is refcount part of Mat or part of the data Mat pointed to? If it stored in Mat how every element's refcount increased to 25000? and why this little change solve the memory problem?
To solve the refcount problem, I tried this code and the memory problem returned again:

```
    Size size(227,227);
    Mat temp;
    for(int i;i<=25000;i++)
    {
      resize(imread(strcat(image_address,itoa(i))),temp,size);
      data_.push_back(temp);
      temp.release();
    }
```

Based on [OpenCV Documentations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae48d4913285518e2c21a3457017e716e) release() in this case must only decrease refcount.Why does it cause memory problem came back again?

(data_ is a member of a class and defined as std::vector)

Comment: first or second snippet, and `data_.push_back(temp.clone());`

Comment: I didn't use deep copy...